# Export Java Application as Runnable Jar in Eclipse - Old projects in launch configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am using Eclipse Indigo and I am new to the IDE. When I try to export a java project as a runnable JAR, the dialog box includes "launch configurations" from old projects which are no longer in the project explorer or on the file system (I deleted the projects).

Is there a way to clean up the list? I want it so that only launch configurations from the selected project will be shown in the list. I have searched on Google and asked a few friends. None could point me to a solution.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
To further clarify, please look at this screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/hdrabva7p/ 
My current project is JavaTest but I get options from an old project named "AnotherJava".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delete existed run configurations from old projects. See this screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/kcj17wnwf/ By default Eclipse stores this configs in workspace but you can save them anywhere. See preferences in the screenshot above. I prefer to save them in project folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but doesn't solve my problem. 

Here is the run configuration for my current project: http://postimage.org/image/4tw5o4m0l/

But I still see other projects in the dialog box: http://postimage.org/image/hdrabva7p/

Comment: Than review files in <WORKSPACE>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches folder. I preform actions I wrote above and it's OK.